# How can I merge two inputtext in blazor form

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have Blazor form with 3 InputText

<InputText Id="FirstName" class="form-control"  @bind-Value="RegisterModel.FirstName"/>

<InputText Id="LastName" class="form-control"  @bind-Value="RegisterModel.LastName"/>

<InputText Id="FullName" class="form-control"  @bind-Value="RegisterModel.FullName"/>

What I need is, if user type a letter in firstname or lastname, the full name value will reflect the changes. But if the user change the fullname field, It will not affect the first and last name filds.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this solution

```
<input type="text"
       Id="FirstName"
       class="form-control"
       value="@RegisterModel.FirstName"
       @oninput=@(e=> {
       RegisterModel.FirstName = e.Value.ToString();
       RegisterModel.FullName = $"{RegisterModel.FirstName} {RegisterModel.LastName}";
       }) />

<input type="text"
       Id="LastName"
       class="form-control"
       value="@RegisterModel.LastName"
       @oninput=@(e=> {
           RegisterModel.LastName = e.Value.ToString();
           RegisterModel.FullName = $"{RegisterModel.FirstName} {RegisterModelLastName}";
       }) />

<input type="text" Id="FullName" class="form-control" @bind-value="@RegisterModel.FullName" />
```

Comment: If it served your purpose, you can vote it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual property in RegisterModel like:

```
         public virtual string? FullName{ get => FirstName + " " + LastName; set {
/*
                var nam = value.Split(" ",2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
                FirstName = nam[0];
                LastName = nam[1];
*/
            } 
        }
```